# How to count number of rows with same field value for a given ID in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For example, I want to count the number of days in a state for each ID. The table Current_State has three columns (Date, ID, State) and I want to add the calculated column Days-in-state.

```
Date, ID, State, Days-in-state
1/1/2017, 123, A, 1
1/2/2017, 123, A, 2
1/3/2017, 123, A, 3
1/4/2017, 123, B, 1
1/5/2017, 123, B, 2
1/1/2017, 345, A, 1
1/2/2017, 345, B, 1
1/3/2017, 345, B, 2
1/4/2017, 345, B, 3
1/5/2017, 345, C, 1
```

I read a post that said window functions would work, but it wasn't very clear, and didn't have the ID requirement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the states don't come back like ABA, only ABC, the solution is this:

```
select 
 date
,id
,state
,row_number() over (partition by id, state order by date) as days_in_state
from your_table
order by id,date
```

You can tell the window function to look at some groups of rows independently using `partition`, in your case you have id/state partitions. If states can change back like A then B then again A it's a bit more complex, needs another query.

Comment: Thanks AlexYes. The states will go from A to B and back to A, but when it goes back (A from B) I want to start the count of days in state over.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select id,
       sum(case when state = 'A' then days_in_state else 0 end) as state_a,
       sum(case when state = 'B' then days_in_state else 0 end) as state_b,
       sum(case when state = 'C' then days_in_state else 0 end) as state_c
from t
group by id;
```

Your data suggests that you might want `max()` rather than `sum()`.

Comment: No, the days_in_state field is the calculated field that I am trying to create. My bad on not making that clear in the question, which has been updated to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Your Days-in-state column does not appear to be very informative. I'm ignoring it.

I'm assuming you have a (compound) unique index on date, id, state. Then the desired query is:

```
select    count(*) as num_days, id, state
from      whatever_you_named_your_table
group by  id, state;
```